# Kinesis processing is lagging by 24 hours

Tags: amazon-kinesis

We have 2 producers and 1 consumer,our processing of data from kinesis lags behind 24 hours using KCL.How can we improve the performance.

Comment: You are probably reading from the TRIM_HORIZON instead of the LATEST (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html#API_GetShardIterator_RequestSyntax)

Answer (score 0):

It is clear you are doing something wrong in the consumer. 24 hours lag is a killer for Kinesis, as the data is being deleted from Amazon servers after that interval.

To improve your experience, you have to do things in your pipeline.

1. If the delay between 2 records on the producer side is 7 seconds, and time to process 1 record on consumer application is more than 7 seconds; you cannot use Kinesis. That is obvious. But if your business need is requiring this approach, you may need to think other strategies. Maybe processing (compute intensive) tasks on a remote server, other than consumer application can help you. Maybe sending the consumed records to a messaging platform to be processed elsewhere? But that seems like an anti-pattern (ie. "Why are you using Kinesis, if you have to use another messaging system?").
2. Do less in the consumer. If you really need to spend so much time with a record, try to parallelize the consuming process. I will use the previous example again, if 1 record takes 15 seconds to process, and if you receive 3 requests in that interval; use or more 3 worker threads on the consumer side. If you are using KCL, you can use more shards to improve parallelization. As far as I know, each IEmitter class (implementation) runs on its own thread. And for each shard, a new IEmitter is invoked. Also, check your hash (partition) keys; that helps homogeneous distribution of your records amongst shards.
3. Batch processing on the consumer is also an option. For example, let's say you have records containing "id:1, name:John, surname:Doe", "2, Jason, Will", "3, Mary, Poppin" etc. And lets say you need to write all these as infortmation as inserts to MySQL. Each insert is costly (everytime open connection, write, commit, close connection.). But if you write these records on a temporary placeholder file for bulk processing, you can make 1 insert request to MySQL with 3 value sets. That would save you the network overhead.

If you explain your business case, data model etc, maybe we can help more.

Thanks.